# How to create Dynamic SQL server API connector in Logic app

Tags: sql-server, dynamic, azure-logic-apps

I have stored SQL server credentials(like username, password) in the secrets of azure keyvault. 
For this, I have created keyvault connector(Get secrets) and SQL server connector(Execute query).
But as per requirement I need to add the dynamic SQL server connector who will fetch the SQL server credentials from secrets and try to login.

So is there any way to make SQL server connector dynamic.

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not possible. Azure stores the service (in this case a SQL database) credentials and connection information in an API Connection resource and this is currently the only way that these actions can work.

As an alternative, you could use Azure Functions to connect to the database, which have many of the same triggering patterns available and allow you to write any code you need (within reason) to acquire secrets through whatever mechanism is most suitable.